# .net compact framework web browser component and html content

Tags: .net, html, compact-framework, webbrowser-control, windows-mobile-6

I'm developing a simple .net cf application (vb.net .net 3.5 windows mobile 6.5) that must present html content in a fullscreen form using the webbrowser component supplied with the framework.
The device that host the appliction has a 800 * 480 pixel resolution.
the application simply show a form wich contains a webbrowser component docked full and no other component. At the load event, the form simply load the correct url of a html file in the Sd Card of the device.

```
Private Sub frmLauncher_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        ShowHide.ShowTopStatusbar(False)
        ShowHide.disableSoftwareKey()
        ShowHide.SipShowIMP(0)
        WebBrowserPanel1.WebBrowser.Url = New Uri("\home\index.html")


    End Sub
```

I'm experiencing a strange behaviour of the control :

1. if the html content consists of a single image or a serie of images, the control show the content at the right resolution
2. if the html content contains text or other html componets as tables or divs, everything seems to be **doubled** in height and width!

Is there any way to prevent this behavior?
What kind of workaround can be used?

Thanks and sorry for my bad english!

ps: after some experimenting, I choose to change every css for the html content replacing every dimension (height or width) with its value /2 . That's a possible solution but in doesn't answer my question !

Comment: What is the AutoScaleMode on the parent Form set to?

Comment: AutoScaleMode=none. But the weirdest thing is how images are handled: if html contains ONLY images everything is fine. I verified this saving an image exactly 800 * 480 pixel, than using an html of this kind: <html><body><img src="test.jpg"></body></html>

Comment: Just curious how you got the `WebBrowser` to run on Compact Framework. When I tried it, I got an `ActiveX cannot be instantiated
because the current thread is not in a single-threaded apartment.` error message. And since CF cannot run with a `[STAThread]` directive. I assumed it was impossible. Did you do something special ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look in your phones settings, you've probably got zoom or increase text size double on to make browsing and pages easier to read since it's a mobile device, some devices have this setting on by default in order to have text readable, hence why it works with images but not with anything that contains text. Let me know what settings you find :)

Comment: thanks for the suggestion...I'll check the device settings as soon as i can